# Azure devops: managing build validation pipelines accross multiple repositories and branches

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've recently set up a basic pipeline in my project that runs as part of the '[Build Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#build-validation)' step on any pull request to the 'main' branch. Within the pipeline, we check for some common errors that might block the application from starting. If such errors are found, the pull request gets blocked.

The actual code of the pipeline is in a separate 'pipelines' repo, and the yml file in my project repo includes it via the '[extends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/extends?view=azure-pipelines)' keyword.

Since the pipeline is pretty useful, we want to deploy it in other repositories as well. What is the easiest way to achieve it? Is there another option than copying the minimal yml file to every repository? Furthermore, the pipeline should also be activated on multiple branches within each repo as a 'Build Validation' step, which seems cumbersome as well to achieve.
When a new repository is made, we would ideally also have the pipeline present by default (including triggering it via the Build Validation).

Having an explicit list of all repo-branch combinations that should have the pipeline, and copying/activating the pipeline via a REST API is currently the only option I see.

So far I looked on the internet for similar issues, but couldn't find a clear answer.

Comment: I think you could you 'automate' copying the yaml file to the build agent in a number of ways including specifying in the YAML to get source from the 'pipelines' repo in addition to the repo to build, using a YAML template, using a Git Submodule (or equivalent), or the 'pipelines' repo could produce a package that is used by the agent(s).